# Mesa works, but unable to start Xserver and GUI with nvidia driver and nvidia-xconfig generated configuration file

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, nvidia, manjaro

I'm using Manjaro OS based on Arch Linux. So I can switch between gfx drivers using

> sudo mhwd-gpu --setgl [mesa/nvidia]

command. But I'm unable to tap my gfx card, because of of wrong Xorg configuration.
Working xorg with mesa as graphics library:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Device0"
        Driver      "intel"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
        Option      "AccelMethod" "sna"
        Option      "DRI"    "true"
EndSection


Section "DRI"
        Group  "video"
        Mode   0666
EndSection


Section "Extensions"
        Option "Composite" "Enable"
        Option "RENDER"    "Enable"
EndSection


Section "InputClass"
        Identifier          "Keyboard Defaults"
        MatchIsKeyboard     "yes"
        Option              "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection
```

Malfunctioning xorg generated using nvidia-xconfig and nvidia as graphics library:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Default Layout"
    Screen         "Default Screen" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "keyboard"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier         "Keyboard Defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard    "yes"
    Option         "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier         "Keyboard Defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard    "yes"
    Option         "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Default Screen"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Option         "DRI" "true"
    Option         "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "nvidia-auto-select"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Enable"
    Option         "RENDER" "Enable"
EndSection
```

Can you help me spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use the NVidia Optimus Driver known as the [Bumblebee Project - Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bumblebee).  [Official Site](http://bumblebee-project.org/).  In short, your Intel card Drives amd NVIDIA is only a Discrete card, meaning render only.

Comment: I checked, and I had already installed **video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-bumblebee** driver. So do you mean to say that, I can only use nvidia to run specific applications and games using `optirun` and not say, compiz and other window managers?

Comment: That is correct.  If you want compiz or another WM, you must configure the intel card to Drive the 3D Acceleration etc, and use Optirun to output the result.  Optirun can also be used to drive, but only at the Application level, for example, using optirun + game name will drive just game name, or optirun firefox will run firefox using the nvidia card.

Comment: @eyoung100 please transform your comment into an answer, quite up to the point...